# How do I import a module from a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, vite, sveltekit

Im trying to use the Vite-Markdown plugin with dynamic md files in sveltekit.

```js
export let mdFile;
    
import { toc, html } from mdFile;
```

unfortunately, this code does not work. Does anyone know a solution?

*p.s. mdFile is a Markdown file e.g. test.md*

Comment: `require` (not sure if this works in ES6 modules) or https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import#dynamic

Comment: @SuperStormer This is not what I need :(

Comment: The `import` syntax requires the `from` to be a static string. A variable in that location will result in syntax error. If you need to use a variable for your `from` you need to use the `import()` function instead of the import statement (ie. dynamic import)